# How to replace src attribute of embed tag using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, youtube, embed, src

In my webpage, I am inserting a youtube video just like this:

```
<object width="640" height="360">
            <param name="movie" value="https://www.youtube.com/v/M7lc1UVf-VE?version=3"></param>
            <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
            <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"></param>
            <embed src="https://www.youtube.com/v/M7lc1UVf-VE?version=3" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always" width="640" height="360"></embed>
</object>
```

Now I have to replace `src` attribute within `embed` tag. For that, I wrote JS function:

```
function replaceSrc()
    {
    document.getElementsByTagName("embed")[0].src = "new_link";
    }

if (window.addEventListener){
     window.addEventListener('load', replaceSrc, false);
    } else if (window.attachEvent) {
     window.attachEvent('onload', replaceSrc);
    }
```

This, however, does not work and after loading the page, the youtube link remains the same. Any suggestions? I went through previous questions with similar content, but they were mostly using JQuery, in my case JavaScript is required.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to replace a value of SRC parameter within EMBED tag of HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636612/how-to-replace-a-value-of-src-parameter-within-embed-tag-of-html)

Comment: What are you trying to do? Because changing the `src` attribute will **not** load another youtube movie, if that’s your purpose. See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/94bEm/

Comment: @David yes I want to change the attribute and load a youtube movie with the new link. So what am I missing?

Comment: @MichalB Changing the `src` attribute is not the solution. You should probably mention what you are trying to accomplish in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading a new video in an embed tag, you need to create a new `embed` element with the new src and then replace the old one:

```
function replaceSrc() {
    var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("embed")[0],
        copy = elem.cloneNode();
    copy.src = "new_link";
    elem.parentNode.replaceChild(copy, elem);
}
```

Note that this only takes care of the `embed`, you might need to take care of the `object` param as well.

Comment: you mean I have to recreate object element as well?

Comment: @MichalB possibly, yes, but it can get messy. If your question was "how can I load a different youtube movie at run time using javascript", I wouldn’t suggest this route at all - I would use the youtube API. So you might want to step back and try another way before you end up with too much of a "hack".